# Super simple query over SPARQL retrieves nothing

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, opendata

I am making a simple Query over the DBpedia Open Data Base:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?name
WHERE{
    ?s :birthName ?name .
}
```

but receive nothing as a result. What am I doing wrong?

> Note: :birthName is defined as a Property here:
>
> http://localhost:7200/resource?uri=http:%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FbirthName

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on DBpedia.org.

Comment: If you're running a local DBpedia on your machine, indeed you have to load all the data. Obviously that's not the case here, which dataset(s) exactly did you load?

Comment: To be honest, these are exercises for a HandOut due today so I did not take much time trying to understand where the data came from. I followed the steps and loaded the data from 
>http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2014/dbpedia_2014.owl.bz2

>http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2014/en/instance_types_en.nt.bz2
but If I use `http://dbpedia.org/sparql` it actually works.
Maybe I am not using all the data from DBpedia. I really like this technology and would like to learn a lot more. Any usefull link/exercises to practise more? 
Thank you very much for your replies @StanislavKralin and @UninformedUser

Comment: `dbpedia_2014.owl` does only contain OWL schema axioms and `instance_types_en.nt` does only contain `:s rdf:type :cls` triples. So there is much more you have to load, at least (specific) mapping based properties to get the object and data property triples. That said, 2014 data is quite old - there would be at least http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/ data, and any newer dump is only available via the DBpedia databus: https://databus.dbpedia.org/